# Bitdefender Blocking Go v1.17.2 Programs on Windows

Tags: windows, go, antivirus

I just installed golang v1.17.2 on Windows 10, but every time I try to run a program  via `go run [package].go` I am getting this error:

```
open C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build2263332531\b001\exe\[package].exe: Access is denied.
```

Soon after, I get a notification from bitdefender that it stopped a trojan that matches my golang program build location:

[image: Bitdefender logs]

Does anyone know how to make Bitdefender not block golang programs? I can't exactly exclude a single folder for Go code as it's in `%appdata%` so any malicious program could put stuff in there.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Seems like a similar issue was discussed [here](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/bitdefender-detects-output-as-a-virus/22152) and also a workaround was proposed

Comment: Thanks @jabbson, I will try that and also try to set the ownership permissions to avoid unintentional bypasses.

Comment: The suggestion there could open you up to other issues, namely someone finding out you have that workaround enabled, and using the directory you've told bitdefender to avoid to launch attacks. Here's another thread that might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010466/ddg#63280742

Comment: @kendfss Thanks, but for some reason Bitdefender stopped giving me error notices after I booted up again the next day.  I didn't even whitelist the folder but it's working fine now.  That's Windows for you ig

Answer (score 0):

Try running `[package].exe` instead of `go run [package].go`. This will work if you already used `go build` to compile the code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).